# Grails 3: Not able to set configuration inside plugin specific application.groovy file

Tags: grails, grails3, grails-config

I am trying to set the below config properties inside `myapp/plugins/myPlugin/conf/application.groovy` file, it seems to be not picking up the values

```
grails.controllers.upload.maxFileSize = 90000000 //9MB
grails.controllers.upload.maxRequestSize = 90000000 //9MB
```

But if i move this to app level application.groovy file, it works fine.

How to get this working inside plugin specific application.groovy file

Comment: @RahulMahadik the settings are not picking from plugin specific application.groovy file. see my edits too

Comment: ohh got your problem

Comment: @RahulMahadik Can you remove the duplicate

Comment: yes i was removed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will be done by adding the settings inside `myapp/plugins/myPlugin/conf/runtime.groovy`